# pixel coordinate to physical coordinate (mm) without changing pixel values in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pixel, calibration

I use the checkerboard pattern to calibrate image from pixels to mm. the checkerboard pattern has squares of side = 5mm and each square has 175 pixels so the conversion factor = 0.0285. I use this conversion factor and multiply the image to be calibrated with this conversion factor. Now, after this calibration has been performed, has the pixel values changed or it is just the pixel coordinates have been replaced with physical coordinates ? below is my code

```
# Load the image to be calibrated
data_cv2 = cv2.imread('x1.tif', cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH).astype(np.float32)

pixels_per_square = 175

square_size_mm = 0.5

# Determine the calibration factor
mm_per_pixel = square_size_mm / pixels_per_square

# Calibrate the image
calibrated_img = data_cv2 * mm_per_pixel
```

Answer (score 1):

`data_cv2` is a numpy array containing pixel values.

Your code merely scales the brightness of the image, but not its "size".

numpy arrays have no "physical size" property. They are nothing but multidimensional containers for numbers.

Comment: Thanks, Could you tell a bit more on how to convert or scale image from pixels units to physical units such as mm

Comment: that is metadata. it does not affect the image pixels. carry this metadata with the image data and use it when appropriate. physical units are meaningless to images, especially when they've been taken with a camera. even flatbed scan of some document merely carries some metadata with it that doesn't affect the image data at all. it is only relevant when you want to print the image.